# Microsoft Access 2010 - Prevent selection of any combobox option more than once

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I have a continuous form that has comboboxes down one of the columns. I would like to  prevent the same item being selected more than once per order.

The database is basically a microsoft web database template that im trying to modify to suit our requirements (Desktop product inventory database).

My requirement is,if for example a user selects the 350CC shaver shown below, i want the shaver to disappear from the list of available options from then on.

**The form is shown below, with the comboboxes down the product column:**

[image: Orderlineitems form]

**The rowsource for the product column is as follows:**
[image]

**The record source for the form itself is as follows:**

[image]

So, having a very basic knowledge of SQL, i would appreciate some help in crafting the sql statement required to achieve this.

cheers

**EDIT - 9-Dec -14**

Picture showing orderdetails cleared off the form and error message.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at indexes?

Comment: hi, no i havent and quite new to this. Please see my comment below regarding indexes. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a unique index using the primary key of the order details table and the product ID foreign key

Then when a duplicate product is selected the system will not allow it to be saved into the table and will throw an error

However this is not available with Microsoft Access 2010 because the backend data is stored in a SharePoint list not directly into SQL Server table unlike Access 2013.

Instead as a workaround you can create a data macro that will essentially do the same thing.

Example of the data macro can be seen in the following screenshot indicated by the red arrow:

http://screencast.com/t/WjU5qws4Ug

Comment: Thanks Mark3308, how would i go about this on a template based database? i dont have access to the table design views. I only have layout view on forms, datasheet view on forms and tables and the only item i can design is queries.

Comment: Please see my revised answer

Comment: thanks for the update. i entered the data macro in the orderdetails table as shown, and it does pop up the error. however, it also doesnt enable the user to delete the duplicate entry and the only way ive found to clear it off the screen is to start the whole order again.How can this be avoided? cheers

Comment: please see picture i attached above showing the data cleared off the form ( Edit 9-Dec-14)